# Mapping 3d coordinates to 2d coordinates using equirectangular projection

Tags: python, math, mapping, gis, projection

I am currently working on eeg signals, so here basically we have electrodes which are placed on head of a person and we get 3d coordinates of each electrodes so basically i am trying to find 2d coordinates from these 3d coordinates but with the help of equirectangular projection ( the same way how we project globe on a plane paper).
Here are the few links for better understanding:
https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-vector-data-python/spatial-data-vector-shapefiles/geographic-vs-projected-coordinate-reference-systems-python/

https://www.coursera.org/lecture/introduction-gis-mapping/associating-points-from-3d-to-2d-y7kIx

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html

Comment: with 3d coordinates you mean (x,y,z) right? and the 2d coordinates should be longitude latitude on a sphere?

Comment: or not longitude latitude but x,y on a 2d plane

Comment: yes, the same, x and y.thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be the following but maybe you can confirm if this is correct:

```
import math

def cartesian_to_spherical(x,y,z):
    r=math.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)
    theta=math.acos(z/r)
    phi=math.atan(y/x)
    return r,theta,phi

def spherical_to_mercator(r,theta,phi):
    x=theta
    y=0.5*math.log((1+math.sin(phi))/(1-math.sin(phi)))
    return x,y


r,theta,phi=cartesian_to_spherical(2,3,1) # fill in your x,y,z here
x,y=spherical_to_mercator(r,theta,phi)
print("x = ",x," y = ",y)
```

Comment: can you share me the link from where you have taken hints for spherical to mercator ?

Comment: Equation is from wikipedia.

Comment: joostblack thanks but i think you have mislabeled the theta and phi in cartesian_to_spherical method, please refer this site for the cartesian to spherical formula, https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/12%3A_Vectors_in_Space/12.7%3A_Cylindrical_and_Spherical_Coordinates

Comment: Also there are many equation in the Wikipedia page so could you please be specific, which equation you have chosen so that i can refer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system, coordinate system is displayed in the first picture.

Comment: Seems that indeed the theta and phi are used for different angles. But does that matter? It is just a name right?

Comment: It's not just a name, both of them represent different angles and also when you are using them for spherical to mercator conversion they will show different results when they're interchanged.

Comment: I understood the equation for finding y but didn't got the equation of x.